# Verifying a Caraousel should rotate after clicking - Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium, webdriver, java

Is there an automation method, via Selenium with Java, that can verify if a carousel rotates after clicking it?

I highlighted the Right arrow as Red box which should rotate after clicking it.

[image]

Comment: Are these three different images or one single image? And does the next screen has the same number of images. It would be good if you give an HTML snippet of this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/10287/how-to-test-image-carousel

Comment: @log_file They are three different images. And when you click on the arrows it might have different images depending if there are more cars to rotate.

Comment: What does the HTML look like for the images? if the text is separate from the image you can verify that the text has changed after clicking on the arrow. For instance: if the number goes from 33155 to 33154 you can check to see if that element is on the page.

Comment: @DEnumber50 Hm, that might be a good idea, ty. And the development work is not complete yet. I was just doing pre-work to see if there is an easy way to do it.

Comment: @Robben if you liked the suggestion make sure to click the answer button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've written an article about the same topic, with examples in Java

http://www.testingexcellence.com/how-to-test-carousel-rotation-with-selenium-webdriver/

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I would verify that when the element is clicked, that the other elements change. So specifically look at the **text** that is being changed on the page. Something like this would work for a verification:

```
Assert.IsTrue(driver.PageSource.Contains("*Expected text*"))
```

Note that this is C# code that I use for some quick validations, and something with more complexity can also be written.